# Clear tableview before adding the data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I just found out a bug I've on my iOS application.
I've two "histories" and one "points". First I tap on either history1 or history2, than I press on the scoreboard to see how many points I've. But somehow it's getting dublicated.

```
 if countedArray != [] || nameArray != []
    {
        countedArray.removeAll()
        nameArray.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    translateCode()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    list = createArray()

    //Sorting the array after points
    list.sort()
    { $0.points.localizedStandardCompare($1.points) == .orderedDescending

    }
```

I tried to clear the tableview before inserting the data like this. But it ended up to clear the whole tableview after all, so it stays empty. Instead of adding the new data.

How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to append your new data after removing

Comment: @wings Yeah, I get that part. But the data is from another view which I'm sending over with prepare for segue method. How can I than reload it after clearing?

Comment: You need to reload your table after sorting the array.

Comment: I solved the issue. 

The problem was on the other view, so.. Once I sent them over to "scoreboard" I used .removeAll() method on both arrays to clear them for the next run.